# NSCollectionView any good for custom drag'n'drop grids?

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, grid-layout, nscollectionview

I'm experimenting with `NSCollectionView` after doing some practicing with `UICollectionView` for iOS. I'm planning to write an app which central part is a flexible grid view on that cards can be dragged around freely and I want to start with a OSX version first before tackling a iOS version.

The `UICollectionView` seemed like a good choice for my purpose so far (with a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` anyway) but now that I'm getting to know `NSCollectionView` for Cocoa on OSX this class seems rather meagre since there doesn't seem to be a comparable NSCollectionViewLayout class and in-depth info or tutorials on the web seem really sparsely seeded.

So is the `NSCollectionView` class actually a recommended choice at all for what I need? Or could anyone recommend me a better approach to get started going the right way with this?

(What I need is a performant, scrollable view with rows and columns onto that sub views can be dragged and dropped around freely.)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it. You have to set everything up with bindings. I personally didn't find it very flexible. Take a look at https://github.com/jwilling/JNWCollectionView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree, not recommended.
NSCollectionView performance is bad.

NSArrayController is an enigma also.
That said, there was a old example of someone rolling their own,
which is good sample code to peruse.
... google "TigerCollectionView".

Your going to run into issues with every user interaction... drag, drop, insert, deferred layout, reload, etc.
Better to roll your own using arrays of dictionaries, so you can see whats going on.

Comment: Thanks for hints anyone! Is the NSCollectionView really so bad performance-wise? I would expect its caching for view item reuse works similar like in UICollectionView (which I think is very good)? If I have to write my own then the caching/re-using functionality will be a challenge.

Comment: Also, tried to google TigerCollectionView but didn't find anything really useful. Seems it has disappeared from the web *gasp*.

Comment: Seriously. Take a look at JNWCollectionView linked above.

Comment: Thanks! JNWCollectionView looks promising! I have yet to get the demo compiled as there are errors shown in the project. Seems it cannot find files in the 'External' folder.

Comment: Got it working. Had to clone with git instead of d/l the zip! I guess this is my best bet in going forward with my app. I probably want to convert it all to Swift.